# Getting all likes on my domain (facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get statistics for likes on my domain. I would like to get all likes (if possible with user ids) for all pages on my domain (which has tens of thousands of pages)

What does domain_like_adds actually return?

> SELECT metric, value FROM insights 
>   WHERE object_id=[domain-id] AND
>   metric='domain_like_adds' AND
>   end_time=end_time_date('2011-01-03')
>   AND period=period('month')

Returns blank, does anyone know what data domain_like_adds returns?

Regards,
Niklas

Comment: I should clarify a bit. I get like statistics on my domain via facebook.com/insights (with a list of urls that has been liked, for example) but using FQL it's blank. Even when retrieving with access_token for the applications that "owns" the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way you're going to get user IDs as that is a major privacy invasion, but I believe `domain_like_adds` indicates how many NEW likes your domain got in the given time period, as opposed to the cumulative likes your domain has earned until that point. It doesn't appear there's a viable way to determine the # of likes of all objects in your domain for all time without tracking it from the beginning and/or going back and summing up historical data.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a sitemap.xml of your site and crawl the urls against the Facebook Graph API. I actually made a Ruby script to do this: http://bobbelderbos.com/2012/01/ruby-script-facebook-like-stats-blog/. I don't think you can get the users that 'liked' your pages, but this script might be useful to find out what URLs are most popular.