# List Recent Facebook "likes" from a certain domain

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

ive been checking the facebook API for a feature where I can request all facebook likes from a certain domain. Lets say my site is www.test.com and i have many pages which all have a like button for each page. I would like to query facebook to see which pages of the domain test.com have been liked recently.

I know about this widget http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/ but it doesnt show the likes individually, and also it is very limited.

Is there some API i can query?

Comment: Anyone? I got a feeling it might be impossible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645500/getting-all-likes-on-my-domain-facebook/5527075#5527075) seems like it's sort of similar to what you're asking for. As I pointed out in my answer to that question, it's probably not likely you'll be able to get likes per piece of content without manually keeping track and adding them up yourself (that is, knowing about each object and tracking it).